# Circuit with LTspice default NMOS model does not work as expected

Tags: transistors, mosfet, ltspice, simulation, nmos

I put together a circuit where I want to switch a load with a nMOSFET, but I get a load current that is unexpectedly low.
I reduced the problem to this circuit:

[image]

As can be seen the load current is around 40 mA while I expected it to be ~2.4A for a saturated transistor (the simulation is done for gate-source voltages of up to 100 V).
What is the Vgs threshold voltage I should assume for the standard NMOS? I expected it to work at any value as it is an idealized model, isn't it?
What am I doing wrong?!
I tried adding a pulldown at the gate, even though I didn't expect this to enhance the situation...

Info: I'm using LTspice XVII from Nov 26 2018 under Linux with Wine.

Comment: Standard switching NMOSFETs are meant to be driven with 10V-15V, but can handle as high as 20V, sometimes 30V, at the gate Note that this is higher than and not the same as the Vgs threshold). Logical level NMOS are expected to be driven with 5V at the gate. Sometimes even 3.3V or 2.7V.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But in my simulation it doesn't switch at 100V, that's what I wonder.

Comment: Hit F1 on LTspice. In the search box enter 'M' (without quotes) and search. Select the "M. MOSFET" entry and read it. There is a default column that tells you all the details used, by default, when you don't otherwise specify a model. The default MOSFET level is "1".

Comment: Well, 100V at the gate would blow the MOSFET in real life. I'm not sure how simulations deal with hardware failures. I don't know if they just ignore it and simulate through it as if it worked or if they spit out garbage.

Comment: @jonk unfortunazely I have no search bar in the help menu. I guess that a problem related to wine... the standard model seems to be so idealized, that it has a constant amplification at any gate voltage

Comment: @Toor *I'm not sure how simulations deal with hardware failures.* Depends on the MOSFET's model and features. I have not yet seen very sophisticated models in LTSpice that would complain about exceeding Vgs_max for example. In more sophisticated simulators (Cadence Spectre) with appropriate models you might get a "**Warning:** junction melting" (yes, that is funny) and/or over voltage/over current messages.

Comment: ltspice tip: you can use F7 to move text labels (comments and spice directives) so that they do not overlap components

Comment: @jsotola thanks for the tip!

Comment: @jonk You could post an answer, because the two existent ones don't address the issue of the MOSFET being intended to be used as monolithic, while the VDMOS is the one OP (and the answers) are looking for. I'm not saying you can't use the MOSFET for this, in the same way the 1N4148 could be used as a rectifier for a 12 V / 5 A flyback output. It's SPICE, no smoke, but also GIGO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was having the same problem this weekend and these answers above didn't really help much because I was still missing so much basic understanding. I'm new to Spice and don't understand the complexities of all the different MOSFETs but was surprised a component so popular was proving so hard to find a simple MOSFET that worked like I have read MOSFETs should work. I have been using the new fusion 360 electronics features, which is the Autodesk merging of Eagle CAD PCB board design into Fusion 360 CAD/CAM, and though it's more oriented to circuit board design, it includes strong support for Spice simulation as well. But yet, no off-the-shelf MOSFETs to pick from other than the standard NMOS and PMOS spice models.  Or, more accurately, all the ones that are there, don't include a spice model and only include schematic symbols, board footprints, and 3D models.

When trying to use the generic NMOS models, just like Sim Son, I was seeing simulation results just like his. Even 100V gate voltage wouldn't switch it on as I was expecting.

The answer, as Bimpelrekkie gave, is the right issue.  The generic NMOS and PMOS models have a large set of variables that can be set to rational values to fit just about any MOSFET, but their default values don't produce the type of behavior one might expect in something like a power switching MOSFET which turns on fully at only a few volts of Source to Gate voltage and can pass many amps of current when on.

But making it act like a power switching MOSFET for simple circuit experimenting, turns out to be simple (once I spent hours and hours and hours reading, and learning, and experimenting).  I found there are really only two variables you need to set to get simple power MOSFET switching behavior if you just want the basic voltage and current curves to look like a power MOSFET and are not trying to do an advanced emulation of a specific component.

Here are the spice netlist commands to make this work in LTSpice:

```
M1 1 2 0 0 POWERMOSFET

.model POWERMOSFET NMOS vto=2.4 kp=150
```

POWERMOSFET is just the name I made up for this model.  The M1 line is an example of how a given part gets defined in your circuit with M1 being the name of the part in your drawing, the next 4 arguments on the line are your wire net names connected to the drain, gate, source, and base (source and base are normally the same so they are connected as is normal inside most descrete packages), and the last is the model name, as defined in the .model line below it.

In TLSpice, the .model line is added as a "Spice Directive" to your schematic (just text you put anywhere on the page that is added to the Spiece netlist file).

In Fusion 360 Electronics, you can add the .model to the text model for the part.  I think, maybe, you can even add the parameters to the M1 line (I didn't test that so I'm not sure).

The two key parameters are:

1. Vto - Zero-bias threshold voltage, This controls the threshold voltage, which is the voltage your MOSFET will start to turn on. The 2.4 volts I used above is just a typical range number for a different power most I was trying to emulate.  The default value for the simulator is 0 volts. So the default current curve starts to rise straight at zero, which is not typical of the power MOSFETs. (Is it typical of any MOSFET I wonder?)
2. Kp - Transconductance parameter.  Complex name, simple idea.  This defines the gain of the MOSFET.  This is the thing that seemed so wrong for Sim Son and to me which got me so confused. It defines how much change in gate voltage is needed to produce a given change in current flowing from Source to Drain.  The default value is .00002 amps per volt². I assume this is typical for small signal MOSFETs (like a MOSFET on an IC maybe?), but it's nowhere near what we see in the power MOSFETs. The value I used of 150 makes it closely match another power MOSFET model I was using that turned the 30V MOSFET fully on with only a few volts above the threshold voltage. The larger the value, the steeper the voltage to the current curve is.

If you want to accurately simulate a specific MOSFET you are trying to use in a design, you should go hunt down a more complete model for it. But if you are just learning, and playing around with basic MOSFET circuit ideas, and you need a power MOSFET that you expect to handle a lot more current, and switch on fully to saturation with only a few volts, these two parameters will get the job done.

In LTSpice this is a schematic to test this type of model:

[image]

And this (below) is the resulting voltage transfer curve of this POWERMOSFET in the above circuit where it goes off (0A), to on (6A in my circuit), over a very short voltage range as defined by these two parameters.

[image]

Using the unmodified NMOS model, this curve below is what you get which only produces 1 ma of current with a 10 V gate current in the same circuit!

[image]

Comment: In LTspice (and ngspice), you should use be using `VDMOS` instead of `NMOS` (or `PMOS`) for discrete board-level MOSFETs.  The NMOS/PMOS SPICE primitives are for monolithic (integrated circuit) MOSFETs, and other SPICE-based software requires a subcircuit to properly model a discrete power MOSFET.  See LTspice help section [M. MOSFET](http://www.ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/M_MOSFET.htm) for more info on this.  You still need to set `Vto` (and to a lesser extent `Kp`), as you thoroughly describe, since the VDMOS defaults are janky too.

Comment: Very true Ste! I found the vdmos model in ltspice and tried to use it to solve my problem in fusion.  Didn’t work.  Fusion doesn’t have that built in model.  It was my struggle with fusion 360 that led me this same problem. In ltspice they have a nice range of mosfets defined using vdmos so there is no need to roll your own fake. Fusion doesn’t have anything predefined that includes a reasonable power mosfet spice model. They are more focused on pc board design and not so much on simulation features it seems.  It’s a work in progress I guess.

Comment: Ohhh...you're using the ngspice built into EAGLE then.  The current version of EAGLE uses an extremely outdated ngspice version.  Holger Vogt (one of the ngspice devs) posted an [update and procedure](http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/download.html#eagle) if you want to update it.  VDMOS has been supported since ngspice-32 (if I recall correctly).  [More info here](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/eagle-forum/update-for-ngspice/td-p/10475933).

Comment: Not using Eagle.  Using fusion 360.  Auto desk has merged Eagle functionality into what they are calling fusion electronics. So fusion 360 cad and cam now direct built in support for designing electronics projects. All electronics and mechanical in one cad cam package.  I wonder if what you say about updating spice on eagle will work for fusion electronics!  I’ll have to explore this!

Comment: Oh, I gotcha.  Fusion 360 uses something called "LibEagle" which is a way to shoehorn in the EAGLE functionality into Fusion 360.  I just searched on my machine (I have Fusion 360 too) and the latest LibEagle also comes with the super old ngspice-26.

Answer (score 7):

You expected Amps instead of the mAmps you get.

I am quite sure that this has to do with the **model** used for the NMOS. You very likely didn't select a specific model nor did you specify a certain W/L. So LTSpice uses a default model which cannot conduct much current as it is likely more suited to model a **small signal** NMOS. It is somewhat similar to an NMOS you'd find inside an IC: quite small and for small currents only.

What happens now is that the NMOS determines the current and since it has a limited W/L it will not conduct much current.

What you need is a "really big" NMOS, with a very large W/L, one that is intended for switching high currents.

There is a library with **discrete components** in LTSpice. You need to see what is available there, then look in the datasheet of that MOSFET (type the model number in Google) and see what its maximum Drain current is.

After some Googling I found that maybe the [IRF7401](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf7401pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355fa0a6c1b96) is available in LTSpice, if it is there try it. It has an Rds_on of 0.022 ohm so that should work.

Comment: Thanks for your research. Even though Id idn't find the IRF7401, thanks to your answer I found the "select MOSFET" button in the mosfet properties. I've been looking for a specific mosfet before, but didn't find a library with discrete components

Comment: @SimSon OK, indeed these libraries might not be included but you can find some links here: https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/the-libraries-and-components-models-of-ltspice-free-download.133690/

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. The circuit is a voltage source in series with a resistor in series with the NMOS. A pulse voltage source is connected to the gate terminal to turn on/off the NMOS.

After I switched the drain and source terminals, the circuit worked as it was supposed to. The problem seems to be that LTSpice incorrectly labeled the terminals of the NMOS.

Comment: Interesting, though that doesn't seem to be the problem since the querent accepted another answer already.

Comment: Yes, in my case the problem was indeed the default model for the MOSFET.